# Javaparser AST variable declaration

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, javaparser

How to get all static final declaration information with line number inside a class using JavaParser.

Example

```
public class demo {
  private static final int x;
  private static final int y;
  private static final int z;
  // some code
  }
```

Ouput is

private static final integer type variable x at Line 1
private static final integer type variable y at Line 2
private static final integer type variable z at Line 3

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple: just use a VoidVisitorAdapter and ovveride this method:

```
public void visit(final FieldDeclaration n, final A arg)
```

In this way you can access all fields.
You just need to call `getModifiers` to verify the field has the static declaration.

To get the line just call `getBeginLine` on the FieldDeclaration.

For additional help you can look here: http://tomassetti.me/getting-started-with-javaparser-analyzing-java-code-programmatically/
Source: I am a JavaParser contributor

Comment: My output is "1 @ line33"